# How to run css @keyframes when element is visible via scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a huge problem with controlling css animations, I want them to start when the element is visible on the screen. 
Precisely I'm making a site that has **overall** height like 8000 px, and the element that has an animation is far down, so to see this element I need to scroll  the page down to it. The problem is that animation starts when page finish it's loading, so every time I scroll down to this element, the animation is already ending.

I've been looking for solution on stack-overflow, youtube and so on, but unfortunetly I have failed, every solution that I found and tried implementing didin't worked so I am close to give up on this...

**How to make this animation run when the element gets visible?**
Can someone help me with writing proper code in javascript?

A small digression, I am making my very first site, unfortunetly I haven't had any serious lessons of coding in html, css nor javascript/jquery in school or at university, so please forgive me some non-optimal class or id's names and solutions that are not proffesional. :P
Fortunetly html and css was easy to learn so I didn't have such problems like this, but javascript seems to be hard language :/

HTML element below:

```
<article id="pasek">
  <div id="border_left" class="tekst"></div>
  <div id="litery" class="tekst">
    <p class="rok_założenia">2020</p>
    <p class="tekst_rok_założenia">Rok założenia</p>
  </div>
  <div id="border_right" class="tekst"></div>
</article>
```

CSS code for article of `id="pasek"`

```
#pasek {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #f4d03f;
}

p.rok_założenia {
  font-size: 80px;

  color: #154360;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
p.tekst_rok_założenia {
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #154360;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

div.tekst {
  display: inline-block;
  animation-name: fade-in;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(20px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}

#border_left {
  border-right: 2px solid;
  height: 120px;
  border-right-color: white;
}

#border_right {
  border-right: 2px solid;
  height: 120px;
  border-right-color: white;
}

#litery {
  padding-left: 70px;
  padding-right: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Could you include the relevant javascript that you have tried?

Comment: There it is, I've posted it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some article on [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/slide-in-as-you-scroll-down-boxes/) how to do this with jQuery. 
I modified a little your code example about IDs to make an article more flexible and I made live preview about it.

If you want to learn more about JavaScript check courses on udemy, freecodecamp, frontendmasters, pluralsight etc.

https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-noether-ed4pd

Answer (score 0):

Javascript that I have tried:

Original:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.dummy').viewportChecker({
                callbackFunction: function(elem, action){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        elem.html((action == "add") ? 'Callback with 500ms timeout: added class' : 'Callback with 500ms timeout: removed class');
                    },500);
                },
                scrollBox: ".scrollwrapper"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

With my changes (classes names, id's)

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.tekst').viewportChecker({
                callbackFunction: function(elem, action){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        elem.html((action == "add") ? 'Callback with 500ms timeout: added class' : 'Callback with 500ms timeout: removed class');
                    },500);
                },
                scrollBox: "#pasek"
            });
        });
    </script>
```

I've been also trying to implement those solutions:
https://jsbin.com/zuqexigepe/edit?html,output
http://jsfiddle.net/toby3105/749yxgdk/2/